# How do you execute synchronous tasks in parallel?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I've got a huge array of financial data. I need to execute 6 (or more) synchronous functions that are pure calculations on this array. I need to do this for every security in my program (between 10 and 100 tickers at any given time).

if my function is:

```
public double DoWork(double[] bigArray, double[] history)
{
    double risk = 0;
    <calculate risk synchronously>
    return risk;
}
```

What is the best way to execute this in C# to make use of multiple CPUs on a machine (e.g. a 16 CPU VM) given that these are synchronous tasks?

My first instinct is something like this:

```
var tasks = List<Task>();
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DoWork(bigArray, days30)));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DoWork(bigArray, days60)));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DoWork(bigArray, days90)));
tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DoWork(bigArray, days120)));
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

But **Task.Run** wants a function that returns a Task, which is unnatural given that these are synchronous functions.

Comment: Read about Parallel class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard solution is to use `Parallel` or Parallel LINQ. Since your calculations have results, I recommend Parallel LINQ. Something like this should work:

```
IEnumerable<double[]> histories = ...
var results = histories
    .AsParallel()
    .AsOrdered()
    .Select(history => DoWork(bigArray, history))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
You can do something like

```
Parallel.For(0, 10, i => { Calculate(i) });
```

To run a method in Parallel. The Parallel class has a ForEach aswell.

But because your question mixed up synchronous and parallel as beeing the same thing I must warn you that they aren`t.

An Asynchronous method ain't a method that runs in Parallel it's just a method that doesn't block the execution of other code at the same time. A Asynchronous method allows a webpage to do the work of 2 different users in parallel. It is usually used when your application needs to wait some other agent finish it's work, like reading reacords from a database or downloading a file.

A Parallel method in other hand is indeed what you are looking for it runs your method more than once at the same time and doesn't wait for one call to complete in order to start another, unless you explicitly makes the Task wait.

Answer (score 0):

You can to it with a help of [Parallel.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.invoke?view=net-7.0):

```
// Run 4 tasks in parallel:
Parallel.Invoke(
  () => DoWork(bigArray, days30),
  () => DoWork(bigArray, days60),
  () => DoWork(bigArray, days90),
  () => DoWork(bigArray, days120)
);
```

Another possibility is [Task.WaitAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.waitall?view=net-8.0):

```
var tasks = List<Task>() {
  Task.Run(() => DoWork(bigArray, days30)),
  Task.Run(() => DoWork(bigArray, days60)),
  Task.Run(() => DoWork(bigArray, days90)),
  Task.Run(() => DoWork(bigArray, days120))
};

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```